# linking with particular version of a library

Tags: cmake, makefile, ld

I am linking boost libraries with my .cpp files. The build machine has boost 1.55 in /usr/lib64 and I have boost 1.57 in my local directory. The cmake generates the following link command.

`/home/ramki/mpich-install/bin/mpicxx -fopenmp -fexceptions -fno-use-linker-plugin CMakeFiles/factor.dir/factor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/factor.dir/factor_jobs.cpp.o -o factor -rdynamic -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams -lboost_program_options -lboost_mpi -llapack -llapacke -lblas -lpthread -lm -lz factorization/libfactorization.a`

The above link command does not specify the version of the boost libraries. Because of this I get the following error.

`/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_serialization.so.1.57.0, needed by /home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0//lib/libboost_mpi.so, may conflict with libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0`

Because of this nature of linking, when I use ldd to dump the linked libraries of the executable, I see it linked with couple of libboost 1.55 libraries. If the machine in which I run this executable does not have boost 1.55, it does not start at all.

In the CMakeLists.txt and CMakeCache.txt, I see that the find_package is discovering the 1.57 libraries.

`find_package(Boost 1.57.0 COMPONENTS serialization iostreams program_options mpi REQUIRED)`.

However during linking it is not introducing the version of the library. How do I instruct the cmake to do the following.

1. linking libraries to use a particular version. For eg., `-l:libboost_mpi.so.1.57.0`
2. specify the library path for this version `-L library path` explicitly. It should NOT link with the library under /usr/lib64.

Ramki

Comment: Sounds like to me that you have an inconsistency between the build environment and your development environment and that inconsistency is what needs to be addressed. So either you should be using the same boost libraries as the build environment or the build environment needs to be updated with the newer version of boost. As a general policy for software development, you should not be using libraries other than your build environment or you will run into exactly these kinds of problems. Consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds in many things but not in software development.

Comment: @richard thanks for your kind comment. It is a distributed volunteer cluster. It is really difficult to force everyone use the same libraries.

Comment: You have explicitly link the found Boost libs with `target_link_libraries(theTarget ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: @sakra The Boost_LIBRARIES has resolved to correct libraries. /home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0/lib/libboost_serialization.so;/home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0/lib/libboost_iostreams.so;/home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0/lib/libboost_program_options.so;/home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0/lib/libboost_mpi.so. However, the link command is still the same as in the post.  How will I explicitly tell target_link_libraries to use as is?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for other libraries. Atleast for boost before find_package on boost, set (Boost_REALPATH ON). This will set Boost_LIBRARIES with full path as 
`/export5/home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.57.0;/export5/home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.57.0;/export5/home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.57.0;/export5/home/ramki/libraries/boost_1_57_0/lib/libboost_mpi.so.1.57.0`.

Use this Boost_LIBRARIES with target_link_libraries(theTarget ${Boost_LIBRARIES}). Thus instead of linking with libboost_mpi.so that could be link to other versions, we are linking with the library of the correct version.